# how to create a generic singleton class in Unity?

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine, singleton

I'm a beginner of Unity.

I had a question while studying.

I refer to the document below.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T _instance;

    private static object _lock = new object();

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (applicationIsQuitting) {
                Debug.LogWarning("[Singleton] Instance '"+ typeof(T) +
                    "' already destroyed on application quit." +
                    " Won't create again - returning null.");
                return null;
            }

            lock(_lock)
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = (T) FindObjectOfType(typeof(T));

                    if ( FindObjectsOfType(typeof(T)).Length > 1 )
                    {
                        Debug.LogError("[Singleton] Something went really wrong " +
                            " - there should never be more than 1 singleton!" +
                            " Reopening the scene might fix it.");
                        return _instance;
                    }

                    if (_instance == null)
                    {
                        GameObject singleton = new GameObject();
                        _instance = singleton.AddComponent<T>();
                        singleton.name = "(singleton) "+ typeof(T).ToString();

                        DontDestroyOnLoad(singleton);

                        Debug.Log("[Singleton] An instance of " + typeof(T) + 
                            " is needed in the scene, so '" + singleton +
                            "' was created with DontDestroyOnLoad.");
                    } else {
                        Debug.Log("[Singleton] Using instance already created: " +
                            _instance.gameObject.name);
                    }
                }

                return _instance;
            }
        }
    }

    private static bool applicationIsQuitting = false;

    public void OnDestroy () {
        applicationIsQuitting = true;
    }
}
```

if instance was null, Why GameObject to add to AddComponent ?

and Why use that FindObject function ?

and Why use Singleton in Unity?

I don't Know Singleton Overall flow..

please give to me Code Review..

As a beginner, I do not know much. I need your help.

Please give me your think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if instance was null, Why GameObject to add to AddComponent ?

If the instance of the script you want to create is null `if (_instance == null)`:

**1**.Create new GameObject

```
GameObject singleton = new GameObject();
```

**2**.Create new instance of that script and attach it to the GameObject that is created above. In Unity, a component must be attached to a GameObject. The `AddComponent` function is used to attach a component to a GameObject.

```
_instance = singleton.AddComponent<T>();
```

> Why use that FindObject function ?

If the instance of the script you want to create is null `if (_instance == null)`, check if that script instance already exist in the scene. The `FindObjectOfType` function is used to find this type of script only. Let's say that we have a script called `SceneLoader` and we pass `SceneLoader` to the `Singleton` class, it will check if an instance of `SceneLoader` is already in the scene and return that instance of it. It will return `null` if it does not exist.

> Why use Singleton in Unity?

You use it when you only want to have **one** instance of a type of script in the scene. Also, with `DontDestroyOnLoad`, it means that this instance will still be there even when next scene is loaded. It will not be destroyed like other scripts.

> please give to me Code Review

You can ask for code improvement on the [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site. If you are new to Unity you can find Unity project tutorials on their site that can get you started easily [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials).

Comment: Can you  1:1 chat with me?

Comment: I rarely do chat but create one. I can stay for few minutes.

Comment: what's your chat room title?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had an elegant solution to this problem (generic singleton):

```
public static class Singleton
{
    /************************************************************/
    #region Functions

    public static T Get<T>(
        bool findObjectOfType = false, 
        bool dontDestroyOnLoad = false, 
        bool unparentGameObject = false) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        if (findObjectOfType && SingletonInstance<T>.instance == null) 
        {
            TrySet(Object.FindObjectOfType<T>(), dontDestroyOnLoad);
            LogManager.Log($"called Get<{typeof(T)}>() before instance was set; calling FindObjectOfType<{typeof(T)}>");
        }
        return SingletonInstance<T>.instance;
    }

    public static bool TrySet<T>(
        T instance, 
        bool dontDestroyOnLoad = false, 
        bool unparentGameObject = false) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // NOTE: method does not need to be called; BUT if called, FindObjectOfType() is avoided during lazy init
        if (SingletonInstance<T>.instance != null)
        {
            LogManager.Log($"{instance.name} called Set<{typeof(T)}>() when singleton already exists");
            if (!IsSingleton(instance)) 
            {
                LogManager.Log($"there are two different singleton instances, calling DestroyImmediate for {instance.name}");
                Object.DestroyImmediate(instance.gameObject);
            }
            return false;
        }
        else if (instance != null)
        {
            SingletonInstance<T>.instance = instance;
            if (unparentGameObject) instance.transform.SetParent(null);
            if (dontDestroyOnLoad) Object.DontDestroyOnLoad(instance.gameObject);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            LogManager.LogError($"called Set<{typeof(T)}>() when given instance is null");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsSingleton<T>(T instance) where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(SingletonInstance<T>.instance, instance);
    }

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
    #region Subclasses

    private static class SingletonInstance<T> where T : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public static T instance;
    }

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
}
```

where a `class` that has/is a *singleton* looks like:

```
    /************************************************************/
    #region Properties

    public static TestRunner Instance => Singleton.Get<TestRunner>(findObjectOfType: true);

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
    #region Functions

    private void Awake() => Singleton.TrySet(this, dontDestroyOnLoad);

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
```

or if you wanted to use abstraction, you could create an abstract MonoSingleton class that looks like:

```
public abstract class MonoSingleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    /************************************************************/
    #region Fields

    [Header("Singleton Settings")]
    [Tooltip("whether Object.DontDestroyOnLoad() is called on this")]
    [SerializeField] private bool dontDestroyOnLoad;
    [Tooltip("whether this GameObject unparents itself")]
    [SerializeField] private bool unparentGameObject;

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
    #region Properties

    private T _Instance => this as T;
    public static T Instance => Singleton.Get<T>();

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
    #region Functions

    protected void Awake() 
    {
        if (Singleton.TrySet(_Instance, dontDestroyOnLoad, unparentGameObject))
        {
            MonoSingleton_Awake();
        }
    }
    
    protected void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (Singleton.IsSingleton(_Instance))
        {
            MonoSingleton_OnDestroy();
        }
    }

    protected void OnEnable() 
    {
        if (Singleton.IsSingleton(_Instance))
        {
            MonoSingleton_OnEnable();
        }
    }
    
    protected void OnDisable() 
    {
        if (Singleton.IsSingleton(_Instance))
        {
            MonoSingleton_OnDisable();
        }
    }
    
    protected virtual void MonoSingleton_Awake() {}
    
    protected virtual void MonoSingleton_OnEnable() {}

    protected virtual void MonoSingleton_OnDisable() {}

    protected virtual void MonoSingleton_OnDestroy() {}

    #endregion
    /************************************************************/
}
```

where the final implementation of a `MonoSingleton<T>` would look like:

```
public class NewMonoSingleton : MonoSingleton<NewMonoSingleton>
{
    
}
```

where you would `override` `Awake`, `OnDestroy`, `OnEnable`, `OnDisable` if you need to. Otherwise, the script is pretty light.