# Array of custom Gameobjects returns null on its indexes after objects has been instantiated?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, singleton, gameobject

During runtime, i first add some items to an array, then write their values to the log(works just fine) then i instantiate them(still works fine), then later i want to change the values of the array items, but for some reason now the array indexes returns null? Anyone who has an idea whats going wrong?

```
public class ListEquippedItems : MonoBehaviour
 {
 private static ListEquippedItems instance = null;
 public static ListEquippedItems Instance
 {
     get
     {
         if (instance == null) instance = new ListEquippedItems();

         return instance;
     }
 }

 [SerializeField]
 private GameObject[] currentlyEquippedItems = new GameObject[8];

 void Awake()
 {
     // Putting fake items into the currently equipped to test that items can actually be transfered to it
     for (int i = 0; i < currentlyEquippedItems.Length; i++)
     {
         //////////////////// In 3 below lines the array works just fine and returns proper values.
         currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().SetItemType((EffectTypes)i);
         currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().SetItemName("I am item: " + i);
         currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().SetItemIcon(RewardAssetContainer.Instance.commonExample);

         Debug.Log(currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemIcon().ToString());
         Debug.Log(currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemType().ToString());
         Debug.Log(currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemName());
     }
 }

 public void SetEquippedItem(EffectTypes _itemType, Sprite _itemIcon, string _itemName)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i < currentlyEquippedItems.Length; i++)
     {

         Debug.Log(currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemType().ToString());
         Debug.Log(currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemName());
         Debug.Log(currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemIcon().ToString());

     //////////////////// In 3 below lines the array returns null references, but why?
         if (currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().GetItemType() == _itemType)
         {
             currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().SetItemName(_itemName);
             currentlyEquippedItems[i].GetComponent<ListEquippedEntry>().SetItemIcon(_itemIcon);
             break;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know the type of  your **_itemType**. But can you try with also adding **toString()** .Like  .GetItemType().toString() == _itemType.toString())

Comment: I tried this allready. 

Im pretty sure there is no other script that acces this array in any way, and the gameobject doesnt get disabled or something like that either. Im clueless as to why it returns null values on me, yet still the items and their sprites are visible in the scene -.-

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code you have presented, is there any way you can post the code for `SetItemName`, `SetItemType` and `SetItemIcon` as they appear to be members of your `ListEquippedEntry` class and I believe this may have some impact. At first glance your code seems as though it should work just fine.

Comment: What is the result of the debug statements you added before the section that's causing the NPE?

Answer (score 0):

I would ask a clarification question, but I don't have the rep to comment, so I'll just take a stab at it...

You have ListEquippedItems coded similar to a singleton, but it's not technically a singleton.  My guess is that the object that SetEquippedItem() is invoked on is not the same object that Awake() is invoked on.

### Ways this might happen:

1. You create a ListEquippedItems game object in the hierarchy.  This creates one instance.
2. You reference ListEquippedItems.Instance.  This creates another instance.
3. You create a ListEquippedItems using the constructor.  This would created another instance.
4. You have 2 (or more) threads reference ListEquippedItems.Instance at the same time.  With just the right timing, both threads could see instance as null, and create a new instance.

### How to verify if this is what is happening:

Add the following code snippet to Awake() and SetEquippedItem() methods:

```
if( this != instance )
{
    Debug.Log( "<methodName> invoked against non-singleton instance." );
}
```

### How to resolve the issue:

Only create the ListEquippedItems one way.  If you want to keep it in the heirarchy, store the instance in the Awake() method instead of when the Instance field is referenced.

If you want a proper singleton, check out this [wiki entry](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton) from the Unity wiki.  It appears there's a stackoverflow discussion on the wiki entry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438184/how-to-create-a-generic-singleton-class-in-unity).

Comment: Thanks you were right, i have indeed created the scenario you explained! 
Rather than using ur solution ur suggesting, i think i will rather try solve the root of the problem, the two "singletons" or it is probably likely i will get other problems somewhere down along the line :) 
Thanks alot for pointing me in the right direction though, ur awsome! I wish i could mark urs as the right answer, but my rep is too low sorry :/

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple links that may be useful to you.

Comment: You should be able to accept an answer to your question regardless of how much rep you have.  There should be a grey check mark you can click just to the left of the answer, underneath the vote up/down buttons.